# Google Sheets: aggregate income by week

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with monthly data. Dates are on column A and Income is on column B.

I want to do a graphic which shows how much money I've received by week.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Can you please be more specific about exactly are you trying to achieve by sharing the desired results and the things you have tried in order to solve this? @GabrielRavarini

Answer (score 1):

Without your data it is a little hard to tell BUT here is what you would normally do,

If you want to graph by week you will need weekly buckets, to do this use formula weeknum(cell, 1) // 1 is used for sunday to be day 1 in a week (the normal). Then just chart a histogram with weeknum column as your aggregate bucket.

Example - 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MoL-3hTCNspuvblgXM_lbHTZGLTMezZVAwuL_Tur4s0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Excellent! That worked like a charma!

BTW, I had to use the ISOWEEKNUM function, as the WEEKNUM function kept giving me ERROR, I don't know why.

Thanks a lot!